# VSCode Pylance fails relative imports

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I am currently running a fresh project with with a venv. In my root, I created my venv, and started that. Pip installed what I needed, and started creating my application. Here is my application structure:

```
deviverse-backend
├── app
│   ├── auth
│   │   ├── auth_helpers.py
│   │   ├── auth_routes.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── __init__.py
```

When I try to run main.py:

```
from app import create_app


app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\Users\madis\source\repos\deviverse-backend\app\main.py", line 1, in <module>
from app import create_app ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

Here is my `__init__.py` in the same /app directory:

```
from flask import Flask
from auth import auth_routes

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # Configure app settings if needed

    # Register blueprints
    app.register_blueprint(auth_routes.auth_bp)

    return app
```

I have tried countless things to get pylance to recognize my relative imports. I have added the paths to pylance settings, I have edited the workspace settings.json to include all directories, I have tried following this issue report on github:
https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/519

I have followed other stack overflow posts about this exact issue. No matter what I do, I cant get pylance to recognize relative imports. I also installed ruff linter, which does recognize the imports(which has removed the errors I see pylance putting out in editor). But pylance still wont recognize and run app.

Comment: Did you activate the venv before running main.py? Did you install your project itself in the venv?

Comment: Note that you are not doing relative imports anywhere in the code you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

> from app import create_app ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

You can use the following ways to make python achieve the path of `app`:

1. Set environment variables: you could set PYTHONPATH to the path of the deviverse-backend directory.
2. You could create `.env` file, and set it in your `launch.json`. Read [this document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_env).
3. Add the following codes to your `settings.josn` to let Pylance recognize the path of `app`:

```json
"python.analysis.extraPaths": ["./app"],
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["./app"]
```